# The $_FILE doesn't send the file in php

Tags: php, file-upload

The problem is that I've created the following form:

```html
<form action="" method="get">
 <div class="select">
  <input name="u" type="radio" value="meme" class="memeSelect" <?php echo $selectMeme ?>>
  <label for="meme">Meme</label>
  <input name="u" type="radio" value="plantilla" class="plantillaSelect" <?php echo $selectPlantilla ?>>
  <label for="plantilla">Plantilla</label>
  <input type="submit" class="invisible selectMemePlantilla">
 </div>
</form>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
 <div class="meme <?php echo $invisibleMeme ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000"/>
  <input type="file" class="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg">
  <h2>Elije las clases para el meme</h2>
  <div class="clases">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <span><?php echo $error ?></span>
  <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" value="Upload">
 </div>
 <div class="plantilla <?php echo $invisiblePlantilla ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20000"/>
  <input type="file" class="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/pjpeg">
  <h2>Elije las clases para la plantilla</h2>
  <div class="clases">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <span><?php echo $error ?></span>
  <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" value="Upload">
 </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the page to upload the images, first have a get form to go to the page of uploading memes or templates and then a post to upload the images to the server.

The first form works perfectly, but the second does not, I always skip error 4 that no file has been uploaded.

I created another file to see if there was a problem with the server or something but everything worked fine. The problem must be in trying to use the get, but I do not know how to fix it.

The PHP for the upload images form:

```
if (isset($_POST['uploadBtn']) && $_POST['uploadBtn'] == 'Upload') {
    if (isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        $fileTmpPath           = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $fileName              = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $fileSize              = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $fileType              = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $fileNameCmps          = explode(".", $fileName);
        $fileExtension         = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
        $newFileName           = md5(time() . $fileName) . '.' . $fileExtension;
        $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc');
        echo $fileName;

        if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)) {
            $uploadFileDir = 'img/';
            $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;
            echo "vamoos";

            if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)) {
                $message ='File is successfully uploaded.';
                $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
                echo $message;
            }
            else {
                $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
                $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
                echo "3";
            }
        }
    }else {echo "algo no funciona1"; }
}else {echo "algo no funciona"; }
```

And this PHP for the get form:

```
$selectMeme = $selectPlantilla = "";
    $invisibleMeme = $invisiblePlantilla = "invisible";
    $error = $selected = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['u']) ) {

        if ( $_GET['u'] == "meme" ) {
            $selected           = "memes";
            $selectMeme         = "checked";
            $invisibleMeme      = "";
            $selectPlantilla    = "";
            $invisiblePlantilla = "invisible";

        } else {
            $selected           = "plantillas";
            $selectPlantilla    = "checked";
            $invisiblePlantilla = "";
            $selectMeme         = "";
            $invisibleMeme      = "invisible";
        }
    }
```

Comment: plantilla and meme field both have same file field name `file`, You should have different name for those fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two reason for this error:

1. You are using same name for both forms `plantilla` and `meme`. You should use different name of file field as both are having same name `file`.
2. `move_uploaded_file` need absolute path of destination. You should use complete path to make it working fine.

Thanks and hope it helps you!!